# How can I complete the quest "Still in the Dark"?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I can't do the quest "Still in the Dark." I hit all 3 terminals after he says "the virus  has jumped," and I still can't get it to work.

What does it take to finish the quest successfully?

Answer (score 5):

### You have 60 seconds to complete this quest.

After starting the quest, you will have 60 seconds to find three correct terminals and partition the virus, otherwise the quest will fail.

Terminals with the virus are randomized, so I would recommend you to quicksave before starting the quest and start figuring out which terminal has the virus. When you figured it out, reload the quicksave and try to partition all three terminals you found in 60 seconds after the quest start or when Scribe shout "The virus has jumped!".

More information and source: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Hidden_Valley_computer_virus

Good luck, you'll make it!

Comment: you can make a hard save before starting the search and quick saving after since the virus's location will be retained when you reload, then you can find which terminal has the first virus, load your quick save and go strait to that terminal and quick save saving the location of the second location and the same with the third